# Position elements absolutely irrespective of borders of the parent element

Tags: css, position, absolute

By default, if you try to position your element absolutely in the top left corner of a parent container it will do so respective of the border width (please see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t52Pp/1/):

```
<div>
    <i>element</i>
</div>

div {
    position: relative;
    border: 20px solid red;
    height: 14px;
}
div > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

How do I do the same irrespective of the border width without having to indicate negative values (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/u75s7/1/):

```
div > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably too add another div around the bordered div. Then given it a style of position relative, ans remove the position style from the bordered div.

This should fix your problem.